# Use the _init_ definition in order to initialize an object in Python

Tags: python, class, ini

I have written an algorithm in Python and now I am trying to make it a bit more object oriented. I have a good understanding (I think) of objects and classes and I have spend some time reading online the syntax for classes in Python. However, I guess my question is quite basic and it would be great to get some help.

I have created a Class XML which contains 3 definitions. I also have used `__init__` to initialize the object.

```
    class XML():

       def __init__(self,f):
          self.f = f


       def xmlToString(self):
           data = self.f.read()
           self.f.close()
           ...
           return station_arr


       def exportArray(self):
           f= open('stations/'+self.STATION+'.txt')
           lines= f.readlines()
           ...
           return phenomena,parameters


       def calcAvg(self):
           split_phenom = self.phenomena.split(';')
           list_of_lists = []
           for e in self.parameters:
              ...
           return phenomena,parameters
```

Then, in the main.py I instantiate the objects and call the methods I want like this:

```
       stations_names ['one', 'two'...]

       for station in stations_names:
           f = open('respond.txt','r')

           xmlStr = ClassXML.XML(f) 
           stations_arr =  xmlStr.xmlToString()


           xmlRead = ClassXML.XML(stations_arr)
           phenomena,parameters = xmlRead.exportArray()

           xmlRetr = ClassXML.XML(phenomena,parameters)
           avg_dict,dict_values = xmlRetr.calcAvg()
```

The error I get is this:

```
f= open('stations/'+self.station+'.txt')
AttributeError: XML instance has no attribute 'station'
```

So I understand what is the problem. Some how I have to pass into the class the variable "station". But when I try to included it in the **init** function I get different errors:

```
xmlStr = ClassXML.XML(f) 
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Then I thought maybe I have to have multiple **init** functions but as far as I know this is not possible in Python.
To be honest I don't really know how to handle the problem. Any tip would be useful.

Thanks 
D

P.s. I am not sure if the title explains correctly my question, but I can not find any correct words to put it!

**IMPLEMENTED FINAL ANSWER**

```
    class XML():

       def __init__(self,f,station):
          self.f = f
          self.station =station


       def xmlToString(self):
           data = self.f.read()
           self.f.close()
           ...
           return station_arr


       def exportArray(self):
           f= open('stations/'+self.STATION+'.txt')
           lines= f.readlines()
           ...
           return phenomena,parameters


       def calcAvg(self,phenomena,parameters):
           split_phenom = self.phenomena.split(';')
           list_of_lists = []
           for e in self.parameters:
              ...
           return avg_dict,dict_values
```

** Main **:

```
     for station in stations_names:
         f = open('respond.txt','r')
         ## Instantiate class: ClassXmlString
         xmlStr = ClassXML.XML(f,station) 
         stations_arr =  xmlStr.xmlToString()
           if stations_arr !='':
              phenomena,parameters = xmlStr.exportArray()
              avg_dict,dict_values = xmlStr.calcAvg(phenomena,parameters)
```

Comment: One question : where did you use `station ` inside `for loop`

Comment: @Moj: I use it in the: exportArray(self) definition in order to specify a path.

Comment: @Moj: Haven't you tried to set self.STATION somewhere first and then use it in exportArray(self) ?

Comment: you are doing it wrong! you have to initiate your class with 'station'. check out my answer

Comment: @Damin you mentioned wrong person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class XML():

   def __init__(self,f,station):
      self.f = f
      self.station=station


   def xmlToString(self):
       data = self.f.read()
       self.f.close()
       ...
       self.station_arr = station_arr


   def exportArray(self):
       #here you need to use self.station_arr

       f= open('stations/'+self.station+'.txt')
       lines= f.readlines()
       ...
       self.phenomena=phenomena
       self.parameters=parameters

   def calcAvg(self,):

       #here you need to use self.phenomena and self.parameters

       split_phenom = self.phenomena.split(';')
       list_of_lists = []
       for e in self.parameters:
          ...
       self.avg_dict = avg_dict
       self.dict_values = dict_values

   def makeOutput(self):
       #call all your functions
       self.xmlToString()
       self.exportArray()
       self.scalcAvg()
       return self.avg_dict , self.dict_values


#now in your main you need to instanciate your class once! not each time you need to call a method:

stations_names ['one', 'two'...]

       for station in stations_names:
           f = open('respond.txt','r')

           xmlStr = ClassXML.XML(f,station) 
           avg_dict,dict_values =  xmlStr.makeOutput()
```

Haven't  tried it, but should work.

Comment: Trying this gives me this error:  xmlRead = ClassXML.XML(stations_arr)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could change the way the solution is organized, to make things a bit easier.

Based on the code you posted, I'm assuming that:

- xmlToString takes the file f and station as parameter
- exportArray takes stations_arr as parameter
- calcAvg takes (phenomena, parameters) as parameter

I'll also assume you are ultimately interested in the (`avg_dict`, `dict_values`). That said, a slightly refactored version of this solution be something like this:

Main code:

```
   stations_names ['one', 'two'...]
   for station in stations_names:
       my_xml_object         = ClassXML.XML('respond.txt', station) 
       avg_dict, dict_values = my_xml_object.calcAvg()
```

Class:

```
class XML():

   def __init__(self, f_name, station):
      # 1 - define self.data
      with open(f_name, 'r') as f:
          self.data = f.read()
      # 2 - define self.station_arr
      self.station_arr = self.xmlToString(station)
      # 3 - Finally define (phenomena, parameters), which 
      # will be used by calcAvg()
      self.phenomena, self.parameters = self.exportArray(station_arr)

   def xmlToString(self, station):
       data = self.data
       ...
       return station_arr

   def exportArray(self, station_arr):
       # you must define self.STATION somewhere
       f = open('stations/' + self.STATION + '.txt')
       lines = f.readlines()
       ...
       return phenomena, parameters


   def calcAvg(self):
       split_phenom = self.phenomena.split(';')
       list_of_lists = []
       for e in self.parameters:
          ...
       return phenomena, parameters
```

I havent't test it, but the most important is that you get the idea.